# Controller Method not returning value

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am building a spring boot application .This is my RestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/bikes")
public class BikeController {


    @GetMapping 
      public  String s(){


        return " show this message";
        }
```

When i paste the following URL in the POSTMAN i get the following message
**http://localhost:8080/api/v1/bikes**

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-06-16T21:19:17.791+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/v1/bikes"
}
```

Why i am getting the error ?I expect to see the message returned by the method s().

My project name is bike and it's structure is below

```
**bike
    -- src/main/java
                  --------- com.globomatics.bike (here is my main class)
                  --------- controllers**
```

And this is my main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BikeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BikeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do the logs say? What is the package of the class? What is the code of the main class and what is its package?

Comment: posted the details of my project structure in the question

Comment: The `controllers` package has to be inside `com.globomatics.bike` package, otherwise spring boot wont pick it up.

Comment: Put the controllers package **under** the com....bike package. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you `@RestController`  is not being scanned by you `@SpringBootApplication`. You can do two things here. Either move the controller in the same package as your main class or specify that you want to scan other packages. Something like `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.globomatics.*"})`. Check out the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html) where all of those things are very well explained.

Answer (score 0):

**@SpringBootApplication** by defult will always scan the same package in which class with main method is present and all the packages inside it. In your case your package with class containing main method is "com.globomatics.bike" so your class **BikeController** should be either in same package or the the package containing class **BikeController**  must be inside package "com.globomatics.bike". Or you can tell explcitly to scan in some other packages by use of annotation 
**@ComponentScan("package name you want spring  to scan").**

change you code to :

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan("controllers")
    public class BikeApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(BikeApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```